# mtry in rfcv function in randomForest in R

Tags: r, random-forest

I do not understand the `mtry` parameter of `rfcv()` of `randomForest` package in R:

```
rfcv(trainx, trainy, cv.fold=5, scale = "log", step = 0.5,
     mtry = function(p) max(1, floor(sqrt(p))), recursive = FALSE, ...)
```

The `randomForest` package explains `mtry` as follows:

> A function of number of remaining predictor variables to use as the `mtry` parameter in the `randomForest` call.

For my understanding, if beginning 64 variables, then the `mtry` used in the `randomForest` call is 8; the next one is 32 variables because of `step = 0.5`, then `mtry` is 5. I wonder if my understanding is right or wrong?

Comment: might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27211765/r-unclear-behaviour-of-tunerf-function-randomforest-package/29513931#29513931

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default function for mtry is max(1, floor(sqrt(p))). So if p = 64, the sequence of variables used is 8, 5, 4, 2, 2, 1, assuming you take the scale default which is log and step for 0.5.

The code is

```
p <- ncol(trainx)
k <- floor(log(p, base = 1/step))
n.var <- round(p * step^(0:(k - 1)))
....
sub.rf <- randomForest(trainx[idx != i, imp.idx, 
            drop = FALSE], trainy[idx != i], trainx[idx == 
            i, imp.idx, drop = FALSE], trainy[idx == i], 
        --> mtry = mtry(n.var[j]), importance = recursive, 
            ...)
```